# Write to a Sybase IQ database table from a text file in R

Tags: r, sybase

I have a data frame which I need to write to a personal table in my Sybase IQ database.

I have written the data frame to a txt file and I wish to input the file into my table.

```
library(data.table)
library(odbc)
library(DBI)

# WRITE OUT THE AWP WAC DATA TO THE DB
system.time(fwrite(AWP_WAC_DATA, 
                   "AWP_WAC_DATA.txt", 
                   na = 0, 
                   dec = ".", 
                   row.names = FALSE, 
                   col.names = TRUE))
```

I then created a table using:

```
system.time(create_table <- dbSendQuery(dbname_conn,"DROP TABLE IF EXISTS myname.AWP_WAC_DATA;
                                                    CREATE TABLE myname.AWP_WAC_DATA
                                                    (
                                                    NDC VARCHAR(180),
                                                    DATE_QUARTER VARCHAR(180),
                                                    AVG_WAC_UNIT_PRICE FLOAT,
                                                    AVG_AWP_UNIT_PRICE FLOAT
                                                    )",
                                        believeNRows = FALSE,
                                        as.is = TRUE))
```

I then try to load the data into the table using:

```
system.time(write_table <- dbSendQuery(dbname_conn,"INPUT INTO myname.AWP_WAC_DATA FROM 'C:\\Users\\myname\\OneDrive - company\\Laptop Backup\\My Documents\\Programming\\R\\Dashboard\\AWP_WAC_DATA.txt;' FORMAT TEXT (NDC,DATE_QUARTER,AVG_WAC_UNIT_PRICE,AVG_AWP_UNIT_PRICE)"))
```

I am getting a syntax error as follows:

```
Error in new_result(connection@ptr, statement, immediate) : 
  nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:1412: 42000: [Sybase][ODBC Driver][Sybase IQ]Syntax error near 'INPUT' on line 1  
Timing stopped at: 0.02 0 0.14
```

I think my syntax is good based on the examples in the documentation which can be found here:
http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.help.sqlanywhere.12.0.1/dbreference/input-statement.html

If anyone can help with this I would be very grateful. Thanks.

Comment: Your INPUT syntax looks ok. Does it work when you send it to the database via its Interactive SQL client? Try to remove the semicolon at the end of the file path.

Comment: Have you tried the 'LOAD TABLE ... ' syntax? ... also, is it possible that the final character of the file name is ';'? Maybe remove the semi-colon